# Django order by query in foreign key cases

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I do have two tables such that,

```
class A(BaseModel):
      name = models.CharField(...)

class B(BaseModel):
      a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      val = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

a = A.objects.all().oreder_by("b__val")
```

Whenever I use order by query, getting repeated instances with different val. But i wanna get only one row from the B model.
Optimized query??

NOTE: Using MySQL.

Comment: Which instance do you want from the B model? The greatest? The least? Some other distinction?

Comment: @schillingt the greatest one.

Comment: Check to see if this will help you. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions